# Plot series in same dyGraph with dyCandlestick in R

Tags: r, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

How to add series with  `dyCandlestick`.
The data has columns `"timestamp", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "mean_value", "ma_20", "ma_50"`. Following code gives me a right candlestick chart.

```
  library(tidyverse)
  dt <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amandeepfj/RawData/master/top_rows.csv")

  dt.dy <- xts::xts(x = dt[, c("open", "high", "low", "close")], 
                    order.by = as.POSIXct(dt$timestamp))

  dygraph(dt.dy) %>%
    dyCandlestick() %>% 
    dyRangeSelector()
```

I want to show `ma_20` & `ma_50` in the same `dygraph`. I tried to pipe(`%>%`) `dySeries`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the moving average series in the graph data: dt.dy.

```
library(dygraphs)
dt <-read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amandeepfj/RawData/master/top_rows.csv")
dt.dy <- xts::xts(x = dt[, c("open", "high", "low", "close", "ma_20", "ma_50")], order.by = as.POSIXct(dt$timestamp))
dygraph(dt.dy) %>% dyCandlestick() %>% dyRangeSelector()
```

Comment: dySeries() works only if dt.dy has that series. 
I would recommend you to take a look at some examples related to this package. 
You can check this [link]("https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/")

Comment: Also, the calculation for moving average seems to be wrong.